# Ionic using multiple chart.js canvas in the same page

Tags: ionic-framework, canvas, chart.js, ngfor, viewchild

Does anyone have an example for using multiple canvas in the same page?

I have something like this in the **HTML**:

```
<div style="height: 138px" *ngFor="let item of listItems; let i = index">
    <canvas #pieCanvas id="pieCanvas{{i}}" style="width: 100px !important; height: 100px !important"></canvas>
  </div>
```

In the **.ts** file:

```
@ViewChild("pieCanvas") pieCanvas: ElementRef;

for (var j = 0; j < chartcount; j++)
{

   let htmlRef = document.getElementById('pieCanvas'+j);
   this.pieCanvas = new Chart(htmlRef, piechartdata);

}
```

Getting always `null` is not an object (evaluating '`item.length`') error.

With only one chart it works perfect, but there I use sth. like

```
this.barCanvas = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement......
```

I Googled, but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution....finally!!!

In html:

```
<canvas #barCanvas id="barCanvaslist{{i}}"></canvas>
```

Then in ts:
    @ViewChildren('barCanvas') Canvaslist: QueryList;
    charts: any;

and afterwards:

```
this.Canvaslist.changes.subscribe(c => 
{ c.toArray().forEach(item => 
  { 
    this.Canvaslist = new Chart(item.nativeElement, pieData[j]);
    j = j+1;
  }) 
});
```

this does the trick